# AWS - IAM User Role Permissions are not Propagating to User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My IAM user is not getting the permissions his user-group/role provide. I would like to introduce my problem through series of screenshots. Not sure this is the best way but thought it would be helpful. I have the following IAM User I created:

[image]

, as you can see assigned to group Administrators. Administrators has the following role policy:

[image]

, the AdminRolePolicy:

[image]

, as you can see is assigned the role admin, and the admin role has the following permissions (trust me the top of this page was IAM->Roles->admin):

[image]

When I login as this user, and go to IAM, I get the following series of messages:

[image]

Notice each one says "ask Administrator to add permissions". However, this user has AdministratorAccess, and I assume should therefore already have all these permissions. I am not sure how to diagnose my problem or how to address to fix. I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: If the account is part of AWS organization, then there could be SCP up-stream that deny you such permissions.

Comment: @Marcin , this is my own personal (free) account from AWS i am using for learning purposes. Its not tied to any organization associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This policy allows the group members to assume the admin role. This means you have to assume this role before doing any admin action.

If you want the user to have admin privilege, you need to add the policy AdministratorAccess directly in the user or group.

[Documentation how to assume a role from the AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html)